# Как унаследовать класс если он создается с помощью конструктора?

Tags: javascript

Есть код:

```
<script>
    function base(x){
        this.x = x;
    }

    function derived(y){
        this.y = y;
    }
</script>
```

Как можно объявить класс **base** прототипом класса **derived**, если они создаются с помощью конструктора?

Comment: Это вы все еще книжку читаете?:) какая глава?

Comment: это я уже первые эксперименты делаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того чтобы связать два класса нужно установить свойство *prototype*

```
function Base(x){
    this.x = x;
}

function Derived(y){
    this.y = y;
}

Derived.prototype = Object.create(Base.prototype);
```

Чтобы добавить в создаваемый объект наследуемые свойства нужно вызвать базовый конструктор в наследнике

```
function Derived(x, y){
    Base.call(this, x);
    this.y = y;
}
```

Различные подходы к наследованию [можно увидеть в справке](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain)

Comment: благодарю, то что надо